# Linux Ubuntu PHP Version is different in CLI and in PHPINFO()

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I am very new to linux and setting up PHP in the server.

When I try to do a `php -v`, the php version is returning a version of `7.0`, but when I checked the php version in `phpinfo()`, it is returning `5.5.9`.

My question here is that how can I make both versions to be the same, like when I checked in to the `phpinfo()`, it should also have `7.0` version.

Your help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First you will need to remove the php by following command. This will remove both i.e php 5 and 7.

```
sudo apt purge php*
```

Now install php7.0

```
sudo apt -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Then restart Apache:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have a ubuntu version with PHP already installed on it. Then you installed another php on it, like xampp.

Try to diagnose your own problem.

Get know which php used by CLI by type:

```
Which php
```

If you want to keep only PHP 5 running on your machine, then you must set the variable environment of your bash to running php.exe from php5 directory. Restart your machine and test it.